# rake db:schema:migrate error

Tags: ruby

I am trying to set up this https://github.com/jamesu/tubehub project and get this error.
I also tried all things and googled, but this doesn't help.

```
root@srv:/var/www/synch# bundle exec rake db:schema:load --trace
The source :rubygems is deprecated because HTTP requests are insecure.
Please change your source to 'https://rubygems.org' if possible, or 'http://rubygems.org' if not.
** Invoke db:schema:load (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
rake aborted!
/var/www/synch/util.rb:8: undefined (?...) sequence: /^(.*?)((?<!&)#|\#)(.*)$/
/var/www/synch/util.rb:9: undefined (?...) sequence: /(?:\#)(?<!&#)(?:\#)*(.*)$/
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/var/www/synch/core.rb:37
/var/www/synch/core.rb:36:in `each'
/var/www/synch/core.rb:36
/var/www/synch/Rakefile:2:in `require'
/var/www/synch/Rakefile:2
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:228:in `call'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:228:in `execute'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:223:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:223:in `execute'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:166:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:159:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:187:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:185:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:185:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:159:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:152:in `invoke'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:143:in `invoke_task'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `top_level'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `top_level'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `run_with_threads'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:95:in `top_level'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:73:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:70:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.3/bin/rake:33
/usr/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/usr/bin/rake:23
Tasks: TOP => db:schema:load => environment
```

I'm totally noob in ruby; sorry for stupid question.

Comment: Hi insci, don't apologise, we're all noobs when we hit a problem or else we'd just solve it! :) It looks like you're running Ruby 1.8 when you'd be better off running 1.9 or 2.0. Can you run `ruby -v` on the command line to confirm, and tell us which OS you're running on? And are you using a Ruby manager like RVM/Rbenv/chruby etc?

Comment: @iain `ruby -v` => `ruby 1.8.7 (2010-08-16 patchlevel 302) [i486-linux]`. I running debian squeeze. And no, i don't using ruby manager. Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest you look into [RVM](https://rvm.io/) or [chruby](https://github.com/postmodern/chruby), but you can install 1.9 via `sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.1`. It's quite possible there are other Rubies to get, so try `apt-cache search ruby` (or something, I've not use Apt/Linux for a while). Then make sure you're on the new version and rerun the install for the tubehub project.

Comment: If that fails, run this: https://github.com/vaneyckt/Ruby-on-Rails-installation-script/blob/master/install.sh. This will setup ruby 1.9.3 and rails for you.

Answer (score 0):

I just replicated your issue and can confirm it is a ruby version problem. Using 1.8.7-p375 your issue arises. Using Ruby version 1.9.3-p545 the command runs just fine. The project maintainer should specify a ruby version in their project, I will file a github issue for them to clarify this. Other answers have alluded to this; use your favorite method to upgrade your ruby, I suggest [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv).